# How do I show Apple Maps turn-by-turn navigation for public transport on my lock screen and Apple Watch?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, maps, navigation

I use the iOS Apple Maps app frequently for public transport directions. In the past, if I was actively navigating using public transport, Maps would display turn-by-turn directions on the lock screen and on my Apple Watch. Since upgrading to iOS 13 this doesn't happen, although I still get turn-by-turn on the lock screen and watch for driving and walking directions.

How do I get turn-by-turn back for public transport?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Apple Watch app on your iPhone.
2. Tap My Watch, then tap Maps.
3. Turn on the alerts you want to receive—Driving, Driving with CarPlay, and Walking.
4. Turn on **Transport** option under **Show Navigation**. If it is ON already, then turn OFF and turn ON again.

   It should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately when in 'Maps' I only see one option: a switch for 'Turn Alerts' (which was already turned on). Turning it off and on didn't fix my issue.